# Terraform not deploying template during VM creation

Tags: terraform, vmware

Update: I tried making a template file using Packer and then tried deploying it using Terraform. No luck there as it still gets stuck trying to PXE boot.

I am new to Terraform and having some issues getting it to work properly. I pieced the code below together from this article https://blogs.vmware.com/cloud/2019/11/19/infrastructure-code-terraform-vmware-vmware-cloud-aws/. I am trying to deploy the VM into a local vSphere environment and not AWS though.

The code will run as-is and the VM is created. However, the template never gets applied and I get the error "timeout waiting for an available IP address. The VM is stuck at the EFI Boot Order screen, which is why it isn't pulling an IP address yet. Any clues on where I'm messing up or missing something?

```
provider "vsphere"  {
user     = "admin@vsphere.local"
password = ""
vsphere_server   = "x.x.x.x"
allow_unverified_ssl = true
}
data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "Teraform"
}
data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "ME4024_A"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
    name          = "Cluster1"
    datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name          = "Resource Pool 1"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "VM Network"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = "Win10-1"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    name             = "terraform-test1"
    folder           = ""
    resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id}"
    datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
    firmware         = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.firmware}"
    num_cpus    = 2
    memory      = 8192
    guest_id = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id}"
    network_interface {
        network_id   = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
        adapter_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]}"
    }
    disk {
        label            = "disk0"
        size             = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size}"
        eagerly_scrub    = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub}"
        thin_provisioned = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned}"
}
    scsi_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type}" 
    }
```

Comment: Well, if you copied it over from the article, there is a closing curly bracket missing for the `resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm"`.

Comment: Yes I noticed and corrected that. Like I said, the code runs fine and it creates the VM. The problem is that the VMware template isn't being applied to it.

Comment: Not sure then. Btw, which provider and Terraform versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using it with a local VMware environment and using version 1.1.5

Comment: I have managed to create a Windows VM template using packer but when I try to deploy it, it still won't use the template.